# Data templates in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I'm trying to have a grid that has items that have a custom layout/feel. If you have a look at the following http://mdavey.files.wordpress.com/2007/05/ldmain.jpg this is kinda what I am trying to do (see the aqua/red pods on the left and the graphs on the bottom right).

Under WPF/ASP.Net I would know how to do this but in WinForms I have no idea (I have never had to work on a WinForms app before). Like in WPF I would use Data Templates.

Hence I was wondering anyone knows of any good resources that goes through this or if anyone knows if its just as easy as creating a custom control, they having a grid that has one column and setting the type of that column to the custom control and then binding the data source to the grid???

Cheers Anthony

Comment: How about implementing the grid as a WPF control, then you can use that in your WinForm app. Check out MSDN articles on the web regarding the use of System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost.

Comment: Is this designed to work on a control level (i.e. you can have a WinForms form that is made up of WinForms controls and has one control on the side which is a WPF control) or at a form level (i.e. the whole form/page has to be WPF)? Also is there any specific reference you where thinking of, as the ones I have found seem a little light on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check Essential Grid - it seems to me it supports features you need.

There is an example for progress bar cell which you could use for the graphs on the right side:
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/windows-forms/grid/progressbar-cell

And they have Push Button cell type which you could use for your pods on the left side:
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/windows-forms/grid/push-button

You might also check DevExpress XtrGrid:

http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/grid/dataediting.xml 
http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/grid/appearance.xml

In any case, I would search for a component - it takes quite a lot of time to do such things from the scratch.